# Fill a Select on the fly with the number of values pass through a variable with PHP

Tags: php, variables, select, drop-down-menu

I have a select that I'm printing through PHP

```
echo ' <select>'; 
echo '  <option value="guest">Num of People</option>';
echo '  <option value="1">1</option>';
echo '  <option value="2">2</option>';
echo '  <option value="3">3</option>';
echo ' </select>';
```

But I would like to write the number of options depending on a number passed through a variable:  `$numofPeople` that is pulled from my database.

Something like:

```
echo ' <select>'; 
echo '  <option value="guest">Num of People</option>';
i=1;
While  i< $numofPeople
    echo '  <option value="i">i</option>'; 
    i = i=1;
Loop
echo ' </select>';
```

Thank you so much

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do list.

Comment: You've written it in pseudocode, so you already seem to (mostly) understand the concept of what you're trying to do. Is your question really just "how do I write PHP code"?

Comment: You on right track, just do some more on how to join string and loops  in php

Comment: @Don'tPanic  Yes, that's my question, I have the logic of what I want to do, but my PHP knowledge is a little limited and don't know exactly how to write my pseudocode into PHP. Thank you so much

Comment: I would suggest starting here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sameer Jain said, you are on the right track, so I will give you just a little help:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
echo ' <select>'; 
echo '  <option value="guest">Num of People</option>';
$i=1;
$numofPeople = 5;
While ( $i <= $numofPeople )
{   echo "  <option value='$i'>$i</option>"; 
    $i = $i+1;
}
echo ' </select>';
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Remember to save this code in a .PHP file.

Notice the `echo` inside the `while`, and how double quotes are outside and the single quotes are in the `value`. This is important.

Comment: Thank you Jose, that worked. I already folowed don't panic link and figure it out myself and that's how i solved it. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
echo ' <select>'; 
echo '  <option value="guest">Num of People</option>';

for($i=1;$i< $numofPeople;$i++){
    echo '  <option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>'; 
}

echo ' </select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something like this:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM people";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$totalPeople = $rows['total'];

if ($totalPeople > 0) {
    echo ' <select>';
    echo ' <option value="guest">Num of People</option>';
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $totalPeople; $i++) {
        echo '  <option value="$i">'.$i.'</option>';
    }

    echo ' </select>';
}

?>
```